# Trigger event on AWS EC2 instance stop/terminate

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, centos, aws-cli

Is there some way to trigger an event (e.g. running a script to push some logs to S3) when an EC2 instance is stopped/terminated?

I have looked into triggering the script using a service in /usr/lib/systemd/system but I haven't had any luck with that yet. I have heard that networking capabilities on the instance can be shutdown before a service is triggered and if true, that could be why the script is not executing correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the answer is not really AWS specific, but it is working for me now (tested on EC2 instance stopping and terminating).

1. I've created a system.d service file:

/usr/lib/systemd/system/my_shutdown.service

```
[Unit]
Description=my_shutdown Service
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
Requires=network-online.target network.target

[Service]
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/path/to/my_script.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Added this service to multi-user.target:

`systemctl enable my_shutdown.service`

Alternatively you can manually create the symlink:

`ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/my_shutdown.service  /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/my_shutdown.service`

3. Started the service and tested by stopping/terminating the instance.

`systemctl start my_shutdown.service`

My understanding:

- Description: a description of our service.
- Before: we want our service to stop before these targets are started.
- Requires: our service requires that network capabilities are available. These targets must not be stopped before our service starts/stops.
- KillMode: none; do not kill our process.
- ExecStart: /bin/true; a command that does nothing but returns a success. Run when are service is started.
- ExecStop: the script to run. Run when are service is being stopped.
- RemainAfterExit:  consider our service active even when all its processes exited.
- Type: oneshot; it is expected that the process has to exit before systemd starts follow-up units.
- WantedBy: the target we want to add our service to.

References:

1. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
2. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#
3. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html
4. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger events, such as pushing logs to S3 on specific events, with CloudWatch... Learn more here:  https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/

Comment: A deeper link to [Cloudwatch EC2 Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/EventTypes.html#ec2_event_type) would probably be helpful, here.  However, once an instance starts shutting down, it's probably a little bit late to think about trying to preserve logs or export anything.  The system stops instances by a simulated short-press of the power button.  Auto scaling groups have interruptible state changes and spot instances have a 2 minute warning, but for other instances, an autonomous, internal cleanup action on shutdown may not be practical.

Comment: Point taken, Michael-sqlbot. Thanks for the deeper link.